# Client context validation of data

Tags: aem, adobe-analytics

As for tracking in AEM I am using CQ_Analytics for a scenario. We have a requirement like, I have to capture a value called "sort type" which is on the page when a user clicks on a button on that page and store it in ClientContext. I have written the below Javascript function which accepts a name argument. Using some code I am able to get hold of sort type value and passing it to the below function. Now my query is, how do I validate whether the name variable is assigned to the Client Context???

I have kept an alert statement and tried checking with multiple combinations but I am unable to figure out what is the correct way to conclude that my name value has been assigned to Client Context or not. Please help with my query.

```
function myFunction(name) {

                 CQ_Analytics.record({event: 'sorttype',
                                    values: {'sortSelectedOption': name },
                                    componentPath: '<%=resource.getResourceType()%>'
                                  });
                alert(CQ_Analytics.record.sorttype.sortSelectedOption);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this post how to make your custom client context and how to store your data. http://blogs.adobe.com/aemtutorials/2013/07/24/customize-the-client-context/

After you create your client context, you have in the example CQ_Analytics.CustomStoreMgr.setTraitValue function that will save your parameter into client context.